# Hostapd failed to initialize in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS version

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, network-manager, hostapd

I am using security conf file but it is not working.

My `hostapd` logs:

```
root@swapnil:/home/swapnil/WPA_SUPPLICANT/NEW/hostapd-2.5_wps/hostapd# ./hostapd hostapd_wpa_wpa2.conf 
Configuration file: hostapd_wpa_wpa2.conf
Using interface wlan0 with hwaddr c4:e9:84:bb:51:5d and ssid "wpa"
Interface initialization failed
wlan0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->DISABLED
wlan0: AP-DISABLED 
wlan0: Unable to setup interface.
wlan0: interface state DISABLED->DISABLED
wlan0: AP-DISABLED 
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan0 wasn't started
nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan0 disabled_11b_rates=0
```

My `hostapd_conf` file:

```
interface=wlan0
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
ctrl_interface_group=0
driver=nl80211
ssid=wpa
hw_mode=g
channel=1
wmm_enabled=1
wpa=3
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
#wpa_pairwise=CCMP TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
wpa_passphrase=12345678
```